# How to use Spectroid app to measure low frequency vibrations?

Tags: measurements, vibration, sound-isolation, sound

I need to measure how low frequency (vibration) changes when going through different materials. The only possible way I found is by using Spectroid app. However, I have no idea of what settings to set up. Test environment would be:

Subwoofer, pointing to the top, inside an isolated box with a wooden board on a top (to mimic
real life floors of the apartment). On the board - material that will be tested. And on the material the phone with Spectroid app running.

Can anyone tell what settings to use? Vibrations will have low dB values (almost silence to humans, but still can be felt with the body (if, for example, laying on the board)).

Here are the settings currently available in the app.
Can anyone guide me how to use all that...?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the normal equipment? Microphone for a specific range of Hz? Perhaps you should consider better equipment or continue playing.

Comment: Google Pixel 3A :D I hope I could use it since I don't need accurate results, but rather to know at least when one material stops vibrations better than another. After this, as more details I can get from testing as better iit is. Otherwise, there is no other way right? Except of going to universities or labs.

Comment: To be honest i would use a accelerometer but yeah you can do this too

Comment: What is "low" to you? 1 hz? 10 hz? 100?